# Ethereum client-go RPC response 403 "invalid host specified"

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm running **ethereum/client-go** docker image with the following flags:

```
docker run -p 8545:8545 ethereum/client-go --rpcapi personal,db,eth,net,web3 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain * --rinkeby
```

This image is running on machine A and I can query the RPC within it. But when I try to query it from machine B I receive the following response:

Request:

```
curl -X POST http://<machine_A_address>:8545 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2÷.0","method":"eth_coinbase","params":[],"id":64}' --verbose
```

Response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Wed, 18 Apr 2018 14:58:44 GMT
< Content-Length: 23
< 
invalid host specified
* Connection #0 to host ... left intact
```

How can I query the ethereum client hosted on machine A from machine B ? Where I can find the ethereum client logs so I can debug it ?

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: How can I query the ethereum client hosted on machine A from machine B

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `--rpcvhosts=*` this flag solved the issue

Comment: It might work, but it's not a good practice for [security reasons](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1502#issuecomment-377795987)

Answer (score 1):

Since `--rpcvhosts` is deprecated, you need to specify the flag `--http.vhosts=<YOUR_DOMAIN>`.

If you need an easy walkaround, you can set `--http.vhosts=*`, but this solution is a bad security practice.